# How to change a switch value in a FlatList in React native?

Tags: react-native, flatlist

My code looks like?

```js
  const listData = [
    { img: require("../../../assets/deposit.png"), key: "Pizza",switch:false },
    { img: require("../../../assets/deposit.png"), key: "Ice Cream",switch:false },
    { img: require("../../../assets/deposit.png"), key: "Hamburger",switch:false },
    { img: require("../../../assets/deposit.png"), key: "Sandvic",switch:false },
  ]
  const toggleSwitch = (key) => setIsEnabled( 
    
    previousState => !previousState);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.spendingLimitView}>
        <Text style={styles.dailyspendingText}>Daily Spending Limit: currently {limits.dailySpendingLimit}</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.limitInput} placeholder="$" onChangeText={(limit) => onChangeLimit(limit)}> </TextInput>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.foodsContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.foodsText}>Foods</Text>
        <View style={styles.limitsListContainer}></View>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.listContainer}
          data={listData}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.foodlist}>
              <Image source={item.img}></Image>
              <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>
              <Switch onValueChange={(key) => toggleSwitch(key)}
              value={isEnabled} />
            </View>
          )}
        ></FlatList>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.saveButton}>
          <Text style={styles.saveButtonText}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

How can I change one value in switches in a FlatList?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to use switches in a flatlist

Comment: I understood that.. but what is your issue?

Comment: I cannot use the switches seperately. They on and off altogether.

Comment: If the answer bellow helped, please consider mark your question as answered

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use a child component?

```js
const listData = [
  // some data
];

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={listData}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={Child}
    />
  );
};

const Child = ({ item }) => {
  const toggleSwitch = () => {
    // any logic here
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Switch onValueChange={toggleSwitch} />
    </View>
  );
};
```